# Page Encoding in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

What's the best way to specify page encoding - using a page directive like this?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Or should I directly put it in a meta tag?

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
```

Eclipse by default uses both, so does that mean I need both?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need both. Actually, `<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>` suffices.

Comment: Note that this implies that each and every page render runs through this directive at the very beginning. To quote the [JSP spec](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-spec/) `(...) for this purpose, they (the pageEncoding setting) should appear at the beginning of the page (see Section JSP.4.1)`

Comment: In consequence, it often makes sense to define this for all your JSPs in [`web.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336923/).

Answer (score 2):

I would think that you need both, don't you?  My guess is that the *page directive* tells the *Container* to compile the JSP using the specified encoding and the *meta tag* tells the *browser* how the page is encoded.

Comment: The page directive implicitly sets the appropriate response header as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use UTF-8, you also need to set the charset for your connection url as well as the request and response.