# Wrong encoding for static texts on a JSP page

Tags: spring, jsp, encoding

I have an issue with the encoding on JSP page. I use spring framework with Maven in my project.

I have set the encoding in

*Maven*

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cxf.version>2.7.5</cxf.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

*Spring*

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

*JSP (through html meta)*

```
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
```

I tracked returned document from server and its encoding. It is right - UTF-8.

On the JSP page there are :

- static texts like e.g. `ščťžýáíé`
- dynamic texts from database

But I have problem only with static text, it shows texts like `Ä¾Å¡ÄÅ¥Å¾Ã½Ã¡Ã­Ã©`.

Any ideas for the solving this issue?

Comment: What encoding does your database use?

Comment: It uses `UTF-8` charset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evidently the JSP compiler (in your Java EE server) that translates .jsp to .java assumes that the (UTF-8) text is another encoding, and hence those sequences. Use:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is there any way how turn on this setting permanently?

Comment: The only logical server independent way would be in the `web.xml`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336923/how-can-i-cleanly-set-the-pageencoding-of-all-my-jsps).