# Edge/IE downloads Servlet instead of showing it

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="WorkUser" method="POST" >
    <label>
        <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Senden">
    </label>
</form>
```

This redirects to a Servlet which forwards the request to a jsp file. On Opera, Chrome, Safari and Firefox this works very good.

But Internet Explorer and Edge download the final jsp page as html file. When you open this with a browser the page renders great. Also the page shows no errors when validated in http://validator.w3.org

The head of the jsp file that it redirects to, looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Do you have any idea why this problem appears?

Comment: The cause of the problem is not visible in the information provided so far. Please make sure that anyone in the world can reproduce exactly your problem based on solely the information provided in the question. As an educated guess, the response content type is likely wrong. If it is wrong in such way that it's unsupported by the webbrowser (e.g. nog text/html), then some browsers will attempt to download it instead of displaying it inline.

Comment: Could the problem be this line: <%@ page language="java" contentType="charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: Definitely. Remove `language` and `contentType` attribtues so they keep their correct default values. You could further reduce boilerplate by migrating `pageEncoding` to global `web.xml` setting. This way you don't need `<%@page ... %>` anymore.

Comment: So this is a thing that eclipse made. Wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contentType` here is incorrect.

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

It must be one of [those values](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). The default value is `text/html` which is the correct value already for a HTML document.

```
<%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

When a webbrowser doesn't recognize the content type, some browsers may for security reasons be forced to treat it as a file download while other browsers may first attempt to inspect if the response "looks like" HTML and then display it anyway.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `language="java"` is superflous. It's the default already.

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

The `pageEncoding` could be set applicationwide as per instructions in the answer to this question: [How can I cleanly set the pageEncoding of all my JSPs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336923/how-can-i-cleanly-set-the-pageencoding-of-all-my-jsps)

This way you can get rid of the entire `<%@ page ... %>` line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved the issue now, eclipse is funny.

Comment: You're welcome. Eclipse generates code based on templates. Likely a template was broken. You can find them somewhere in preferences.

Comment: One more question: It's pretty interesting that if I add the pageEncoding="UTF-8" it's not encoded in UTF-8 but if I don't add the line and leave it: It's correctly encoded. Any idea why this is happening?