# Rendered JSP markup has garbled UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, utf-8

I modified [the embedded-jetty project](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java) to create [a stand-alone jsp-viewer](https://github.com/fatso83/jsp-viewer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fatso83/jspviewer/Main.java) (one file with full source code). The result works fine, but it has a problem in displaying JSPs containing special glyphs. The problem is *not* that the `Content-Type` is not set when transmitting the markup, but that the rendered markup is garbled (in `view-source` or via `curl`). The JSP files must be read using the wrong character encoding, but starting the jvm with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` does nothing.

These strings

```
Butikknavn – et smartere valg
få ekstra fordeler når
```

becomes

```
Butikknavn â<80><93> et smartere valg
fÃ¥ ekstra fordeler nÃ¥r
```

Edit: Just to state the obvious, the content header is already set, as can be seen from the raw HTTP response

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Does your JSP specify the `pageEncoding` and `contentType`? I.e. does it contain something like `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`?

Comment: Adding `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` did the trick! The other attributes had no effect. Mind posting that as an answer so I can give you some points? P.S. Do you know how to do that programmatically so this is not needed on each page? The normal Tomcat server does the right thing out of the box without needing this, so it is possible somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

to your JSP file(s).

The `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` should do the `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` part for the whole Jetty instance, regrettably, as you've mentioned, it doesn't. You might also try to add `<page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>` to your `web.xml` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336923/how-can-i-cleanly-set-the-pageencoding-of-all-my-jsps)), but I've never tried it.

Comment: there is no web.xml as I am running an embedded jetty instance, as noted.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP response is probably missing the content-type header. Try adding one as follows:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: As I explicitly mentioned in my first paragraph, this is _not_ the problem. It is not how the browser renders the web page, but the transmitted markup that is the problem. The content type header is already set.

Comment: @Josef Chocholacek's answer had the right details, as that specified the page encoding. I would still have liked to have it done programmatically though.